# My Adobe Flash plugin has stopped working and cannot be reinstalled

Tags: flash, adobe

My Adobe Flash plugin has stopped working on Ubuntu 12.04. I cannot see any videos. When I try to install it again, the following things appear on my terminal:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/salty# sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
root@ubuntu:/home/salty#
```

What should I do now?

Comment: There is a mistake in the third line. It should say: sudo apt-get **install** flashplugin-installer (I can't add comments because I don't have at least 50 reputation, so I wrote it as an answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with a text editor. Uncomment (Remove the preceeding #) on the lines:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

In Ubuntu 16.04, this worked:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

In the terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Answer (score 1):

**Installation steps of flash plugins** 
Step 1: Add following line in sources.list (**sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list**)

```
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main multiverse
```

Step 2: Update apt-get

```
   sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3: install flash-plugin

```
   sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: This finally worked on 14.04 LTS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enter

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get ugrade && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

After that, you should have a functional Flash for your browser.

And please don't work as **root**! Do the commands given from your normal user account.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/salty# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:/home/salty# sudo apt-get flashplugin-installer
E: Invalid operation flashplugin-installer

Comment: Try from a normal user account. You should **not** be using root.

Comment: @LovelySinha de exit command to return normal user

Answer (score 0):

`flashplugin-installer` is for the 32-bit version.

On 64-bit you should use `adobe-flashplugin`! [This article has the solution](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-flash-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/):

1. Open `Software & Updates`
2. Go to `Other Software`
3. Select the two `Canonical Partners` options
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get purge adobe-flash{plugin,-properties-gtk}`
6. `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

I've tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 this worked for me:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

     48 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
     49 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```